# replace some entries simultaniously in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'users' the attributes in it are 'id' , 'name', 'gender'. Suppose I want to replace all the replace all the values M with F and all the F with M inside the gender attribute. What sql should I write in mysql to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `UPDATE` statement that toggles the `gender` column:

```
UPDATE users 
SET gender = IF(gender='M','F','M');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hunter McMilen.. Can u please describe how is it working. or post some link or any reference from where i can learn how is this happening.

Comment: The query examines each row in the `users` table and looks at the `gender` column. If the `gender` column equals `M` it sets it to `F`, otherwise it sets it `M`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid swapping the same value twice, and to add more flexibility, I'd split this into three queries.

```
UPDATE users SET gender='X' WHERE gender='M';
UPDATE users SET gender='M' WHERE gender='F';
UPDATE users SET gender='F' WHERE gender='X';
```

Comment: You won't toggle the same value twice, because each row is only examined once

Comment: Of course that's true for the example above. For this user case, your solution is better. :)